# Who pays if a pedestrian knocks me off my motorbike?

Tags: united-kingdom, traffic

I live in UK and it seems that for most pedestrians and cyclists road signs are just a decoration. I often had pedestrians dash through red lights, even if I have engaged the crossing. Being on a motorbike, it wouldn't take much to tip me over if a pedestrian were to run into me. If that happened, who would pay for the damage, since pedestrians don't have insurance?

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with UK road traffic terminology, can you explain what "engaged the crossing" means?  I have a guess, but it's probably better if you just tell us.

Comment: @phoog sorry I thought that was plain English. By "engaged the crossing" I mean that I am already occupying the crossing with the bike.

Comment: I think in the US one would more commonly hear "entered" in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Some pedestrians *do* have insurance, of course, but we can assume that the one in your hypothetical did not.  Before we think about insurance, though, we need to think about liability.  We don't need to think about it too much, though, since it seems to be one of the assumptions of the hypothetical that the pedestrian is fully liable.

In that case, the pedestrian's liability insurance, if any, might cover (some of) the pedestrian's liabilities.  To the extent that the insurance does not cover them, or if it does not exist, the pedestrian will be, well, liable for the rest.

To the extent that the pedestrian cannot afford to cover the (remaining) liability, your insurance may do so, if it includes coverage for losses that you've incurred but cannot collect from the liable party.

If there remains any uncovered amount, you will have to pay that out of pocket.

Comment: Are you in UK? Doesn't seem very common here for pedestrians to have insurance :)

Comment: @algiogia I am not in the UK. I have homeowners' insurance, which includes some general liability coverage, as do most homeowners' and renters' policies. Is that not usually the case in the UK?

Comment: No. Home insurance only covers building damage and sometimes theft and/or damage of gadgets.